# Querying data from Data Views vs SendLog and how large is too large for SendLog?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

So I've been writing these queries to get a summarized report of Opens, Clicks, Sent, Delivered, DeliveryRate.

To date I've been getting this data from the Data Views, but I ran into a snag.

We have been for the past three months recording attributes in every send using the __AdditionalEmailAttribute fields under properties.

Those attributes are stored in the SendLog, but as far as I can tell, there is nowhere else to grab them from. Is that right?

I can rejigger my queries to pull everything from the SendLog, but my SendLog is 33,504,805 rows at the time of this post, and I don't think we have any plans to clear it any time soon.

Is that HUGE? Is it safe to run queries on such a large DE?

What's better, performance wise? Querying the Data Views or the SendLog? I guess they are all just tables in the system so maybe it doesn't matter, but the size of the SendLog is really concerning me.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: You should always query data views and sendlogs based on a where clause that ties down the data to something a bit more relevant like getting all data where EventDate is equal to whatever you need it to be. But getting all the data from the data views is definitely going to cause you performance issues and especially if you are joining multiple data views.

Comment: I'm doing it with separate queries, so not a lot of joins. But I don't like how messy it is and there are several steps to make it work, and a lot of queries to keep track of.

Comment: You should definitely look at controlling the size of your send log, but Chris is correct, IMHO. It's a bit of an ordeal now with an account in flight, but putting a retention policy on the table's a good design and hive off records somewhere else. On larger data, lots of queries is the most reliable way of running reports/automations without timeouts. Not elegant, but reducing the amount of data you're working with for a given report's the way to go. Your Send Log has an index on [JobID, ListID, BatchID, SubscriberID]. Try and always access it using the index.

Comment: @AndrewMcLeod, what do you mean an index? So how big is too big for the SendLog? And how would I hive off records? To another table you mean?

Comment: @garek007 Indexes improve the performance of queries you execute that include the indexed fields in the WHERE clause or joins in your query - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index. Marketing Cloud automatically creates indexes on the fields mentioned above for this data extension, on fields you define as the Primary Key of your Data Extension or on fields that you define in your join when you add to Contact Builder. When you need to run a report or select data from such larger tables as part of an automation, for performance reasons, break the data down into chunks where you can.

Comment: For example, if you need to get clicks from people sent the Welcome Journey emails last week, think about first selecting from your Send Log into a staging DE all Send Log records where the JobID is in your _Job data view and specify "a.jobid = b.jobid" as the first part of your join from Send Log to _Sent and then restrict your send log records in the WHERE clause based on date. Then go get clicks, bounces etc to intermediary tables joining to this first staging table before running your final report/selection.

Comment: This way, you're accessing the data views in an optimal way (they have similar JobID, ListID, BatchID, SubscriberID indexes) and reducing the size of the data that your final query's working with.

There's no hard limit to the size of these tables. There's a trade off with performance of reporting and you'll have to work harder and harder to tune your queries to stop timeouts as the tables get ever larger. As a rough guide, you'll be working pretty hard with any tables in the tens of millions, but you could write terrible SQL against tables with 10K records.

Comment: "Hiving Off" records - the simplest way would have been to put in place data retention on your Send Log when it was created. You could consider creating a new Send Log table with Data Retention after you back up your current send log to a DE not created with the send logging template and then delete the original send log. That'd take a bit of orchestration with a production account in flight, but probably the neatest option in the long run. Less daunting would be to back up your current send log to a new DE and clear the data in your send log. You could automate this process.

Comment: Thank you @Macca you should add this as the answer. Would the write rule to this "staging" data extension be an update or would I do one final step to combine DEs into an OVERWRITE data extension?

Comment: Haha! Indeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on a similar problem. That send log is definitely a performance concern. I would suggest creating a separate process that breaks the tables into smaller chunks and use primary keys on the target data extensions

Comment: That's what I am doing now, but I don't like it. a lot of items to keep track of. Maybe when I'm done I'll post my query so it can help others.